# How to pass arguments to a bash script running under MinGW on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, shell, mingw

I have a bash script which takes two arguments .

On OS X I can invoke the script as follows:

```
./my-script arg1 arg2
```

and both arguments are passed to the script.

I have MinGW installed on Windows and when I invoke the script as follows:

```
my-script arg1 arg2
```

the arguments are not passed to the script.

However if I invoke it as follows:

```
bash my-script arg1 arg2
```

the arguments are passed to the script.

Is there is another way to pass the arguments without having to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In OS X/Linux the terminal itself is [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) and that can process shell script. But in the case of windows it does not use bash for terminal that is why you want install mingw to get bash itself. So if you want to execute scipt you want to execute bash and then input the script. So in [command prompt](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsc/p/command-prompt.htm) you have to give `bash my-script arg1 arg2`. In windows explorer you can set *.sh extension to bash so by clicking on script it will execute bash. But you can't give arguments for scripts. In conclusion it is not possible to execute shell scripts without giving `bash`.

For windows my suggestion is to go with [powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx) scripts which is new or old [batch scripts](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting).